# Generate underline Waves itext7

Tags: java, itext7

How can I draw specific underline between :

```
String s = "This text is underlined with a dashed line";
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
Text text;
for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
    text = new Text(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    paragraph.add(text);
    text.setNextRenderer(new DashedLineTextRenderer(text));
}

doc.add(paragraph);
doc.close();
```

```
private static class DashedLineTextRenderer extends TextRenderer {

    public DashedLineTextRenderer(Text textElement) {
        super(textElement);
    }

    // If renderer overflows on the next area, iText uses getNextRender() method to create a renderer for the overflow part.
    // If getNextRenderer isn't overriden, the default method will be used and thus a default rather than custom
    // renderer will be created
    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {

        return new DashedLineTextRenderer((Text) modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        Rectangle rect = this.getOccupiedAreaBBox();
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        canvas.moveTo(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());

        canvas.curveTo(rect.getLeft()+100,rect.getBottom()+5,
        rect.getLeft()+150,rect.getBottom()-2,rect.getLeft()+200,rect.getBottom()-5);
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

if i do with single element text it works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkZjQ.png)

How i can define where draw canvas if there are several text elements

Comment: In general case, where do you want your line to be drawn? A paragraph can consist of multiple lines. Do you want the underline only after the first line? Only after the last line? After each line? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is underspecified (see clarifying comment). Basically to avoid the overlap as on the screenshot:

[image: bad result]

You can customize the renderer for the `Paragraph`, not for the `Text`:

```
private static class WaveUnderlinedParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    public WaveUnderlinedParagraphRenderer(Paragraph paragraph) {
        super(paragraph);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        super.draw(drawContext);
        Rectangle rect = this.getOccupiedAreaBBox();
        PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();
        canvas.moveTo(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom());

        canvas.curveTo(rect.getLeft() + 100, rect.getBottom() + 5,
                rect.getLeft() + 150, rect.getBottom() - 2, rect.getLeft() + 200, rect.getBottom() - 5);
        canvas.stroke();
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new WaveUnderlinedParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
    }
}
```

```
Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);
String s = "This text is underlined with a dashed line";
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
Text text;
for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
    text = new Text(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    paragraph.add(text);
}

paragraph.setNextRenderer(new WaveUnderlinedParagraphRenderer(paragraph));
doc.add(paragraph);
doc.close();
```

And get the following result:

[image: result]

Comment: Sorry for not specifying I need to add several Text to a paragraph. I need TextRenderer Event for severeral text, as I indicated above:
text = new Text(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    paragraph.add(text);
    text.setNextRenderer(new DashedLineTextRenderer(text));
Can i do this?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <s.length() ; i++) {
    text = new Text(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    paragraph.add(text);
    text.setNextRenderer(new DashedLineTextRenderer(text));
}
paragraph.add("second text");

Comment: It's a good approach to ask another well-specified question instead of iterating on this one until you are satisfied. But do note that I also add several Text elements into a Paragraph in my solution. So not sure what does not work

Comment: if i need add underLine with other text but in this paragraph, for example
 text1 = new Text("one text") // with underline
paragraph.add(text)
 text2 = new Text("second text") // without underline
paragraph.add(text2)
 text3 = new Text("third text") // with underline
paragraph.add(text3)

Comment: It's a good approach to ask a new question with all those additional details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779471/event-underline-with-meny-text-element-itext7